# How can I interpret the word "Kickstarter-friendly"

Tags: meaning

How can I interpret the word "Kickstarter-friendly" here?

> Though ChefSteps is not selling this product at Williams-Sonoma or Macy's, Joule will likely become a competitor in the hot, Kickstarter-friendly immersion circulator market.

<sup>[(Source)](http://www.eater.com/2015/11/24/9788798/chefsteps-sous-vide-gabe-newell-immersion-circulator)</sup>

I know that Kickstarter is a global crowdfunding platform, but can I change it to another word or phrase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a Kickstarter-friendly product is a product whose fund-raising strategy **works well with** Kickstarter, or **is designed for** Kickstarter (that is, getting funds from a large number of people).

EDIT: Perhaps the phrases marked in bold will help you translate the *friendly* part into Russian. (You will probably have to alter the syntax and/or split your sentence into two and rewrite. Try *рынок, где многие проекты финансируются с помощью краудфандинга* or similar.)

Answer (score 2):

As you say yourself, Kickstarter is a crowdfunding platform. How about 'crowdfunding-friendly', then?

Comment: The word friendly is hard to translate into Russian. That is my problem with it

Comment: I'm not really sure how translation into Russian factors into English language. Given this is an English language Stack Exchange, I'm afraid we won't really be able to help with translation efforts. You may want to try the [Russian Language Stack Exchange](http://russian.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: No, I understand that people here won't help me to translate, but it usually helps when you explain the meaning in English.